# How to display product availability in Opportunity Products Grid footer?

Tags: acumatica

In Sales Order documents grid footer. It displays the product's availability.

[image]

How to do the same in Opportunity products grid ?
More so, how do you enforce it to be displayed at the footer
instead of a simple grid column ? Is there such attribute ?

Thanks for the replies.

[image]

Comment: Opportunity products grid? Where is this grid? Which entry?

Comment: Organization > Customer Management > Work Area > Enter > Opportunities (Click existing/start new to open page CR304000) > Products tab

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we compare to sales order, the sales order line gets its value from LSSOLine during `Availabilty_FieldSelecting`. The wire-up on the page is on the tab via `StatusField="Availability"`. We can do something similar by adding an unbound extension field and then during a field selecting fill in the value. An alternative would be to implement an `LSCROpportunityProducts` class that is inherits `LSSelect` similar to `LSSoLine` (a better preferred solution). To keep this simple and focus on just getting the field to display text, I will use an extension field and a simple field selecting in the extension graph for opportunity.

**(1)** In a dac extension, create an unbound field (MyAvailability is the example field):

```
[PXTable(typeof(CROpportunityProducts.cROpportunityID), typeof(CROpportunityProducts.cROpportunityProductID), IsOptional = true)]
[Serializable]
public class CROpportunityProductsMyExtension : PXCacheExtension<CROpportunityProducts>
{
    #region MyAvailability
    public abstract class myAvailability : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected string _MyAvailability;
    [PXString(IsUnicode = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Product Availability", Enabled = false)]
    public virtual string MyAvailability
    {
        get
        {
            return this._MyAvailability;
        }
        set
        {
            this._MyAvailability = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

**(2)** On the opportunity products tab, wire up the new field as the grid status value by setting property `StatusField`. The page needs modified to add this value and should look something like this when added *(requires screen customization in your project -> actions edit ASPX and locate ProductsGrid to paste in your StatusField and value)*:

```
<px:PXGrid ID="ProductsGrid" SkinID="Details" runat="server" Width="100%" 
Height="500px" DataSourceID="ds" ActionsPosition="Top" BorderWidth="0px" 
SyncPosition="true" StatusField="MyAvailability">
```

**(3)** Now in a graph extension populate the field:

**Edit**: The use of `Current<>` does not always contain the correct currently highlighted row in the UI. Switched to `Required<>` based on the `PXFieldSelectingEventArgs.Row` and the results are correct for multiple rows in the products tab.

```
public class CROpportunityMaintMyExtension : PXGraphExtension<OpportunityMaint>
{
    public virtual void CROpportunityProducts_MyAvailability_FieldSelecting(PXCache sender, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        var row = (CROpportunityProducts) e.Row;
        if (row == null)
        {
            e.ReturnValue = string.Empty;
            return;
        }

        INLocationStatus locationStatus = PXSelectGroupBy<INLocationStatus,
            Where<INLocationStatus.inventoryID, Equal<Required<CROpportunityProducts.inventoryID>>,
                And2<Where<INLocationStatus.subItemID, Equal<Required<CROpportunityProducts.subItemID>>,
                        Or<Not<FeatureInstalled<PX.Objects.CS.FeaturesSet.subItem>>>>,
                    And<Where<INLocationStatus.siteID, Equal<Required<CROpportunityProducts.siteID>>,
                        Or<Required<CROpportunityProducts.siteID>, IsNull>>>>>,
            Aggregate<Sum<INLocationStatus.qtyOnHand, Sum<INLocationStatus.qtyAvail>>>
        >.Select(sender.Graph, row.InventoryID, row.SubItemID, row.SiteID, row.SiteID);

        // Need to convert to transaction UOM... (this is always base units)

        decimal? qtyOnHand = locationStatus?.QtyOnHand;
        decimal? qtyAvail = locationStatus?.QtyAvail;

        e.ReturnValue = $"Qty On hand = {qtyOnHand.GetValueOrDefault()} ; Qty Avail = {qtyAvail.GetValueOrDefault()}";
    }
}
```

The results:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed example Brendan. I copied your code in the _FieldSelecting event. And it's now displaying something in the grid footer. However, if there's more than one products. The value is not changing. You think it there could be something in the locationStatus  selection ?

Comment: Yes it does appear that using Current<> in the BQL in FieldSelecting is not correct always. I will update the answer as I have it working for multiple lines.