# Display Inventory summary line found in SOOrderEntry on other pages

Tags: acumatica

To be more specific, I am referring to the line contained within the SOLine grid:
[image]

Is there an easy way to implement the same function they are using to generate this, or would it just be easier if I wrote my own? I did find how to attach it to a grid:

```
<px:PXGrid ID="grid" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" Width="100%"
   TabIndex="100" SkinID="DetailsInTab" StatusField="Availability" 
   SyncPosition="True" Height="473px">
```

Specifically the StatusField attribute of the PXGrid. I also found that the code to perform the action is located in ~/App_Data/CodeRepository/PX.Objects/SO/Descriptor/Attribute.cs. I believe I can imitate the logic that this performs, but I'd like to use it instead of recreating it if that is possible.

Comment: I believe the easy way would indeed be a wholesale copy/paste of LSSOLine.Availability_FieldSelecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this should give you what you need...

[How to display product availability in Opportunity Products Grid footer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45025533/how-to-display-product-availability-in-opportunity-products-grid-footer)

The same logic can be used for any page with a grid.

Comment: Thanks Brendan. I used the information you gave me and altered it to how I needed it. I was hoping that there was a set function instead of needed to do queries, but I'm glad you had the table I had to fetch the info from and how.