# How to process Quality On Hand (Customization column) base on the UOM Column in PO 301000 Screen

Tags: acumatica

I have the Qty On Hand in PO301000 screen:

Here is the code i've archived

```
public class POLine_Extension : PXCacheExtension<POLine> {
  [PXDecimal]
  [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Qty On Hand", Enabled = false)]
  [PXDBScalar(typeof(
Search<INSiteStatus.qtyOnHand,
  Where<INSiteStatus.inventoryID, Equal<POLine.inventoryID>,
    And<INSiteStatus.siteID, Equal<POLine.siteID>>>>))]
public virtual decimal? QtyOnHand { get; set; }
public abstract class qtyOnHand : IBqlField {}
 }

public virtual void POLine_InventoryID_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateQtyAvailable(sender, e);
}
public virtual void POLine_SiteID_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateQtyAvailable(sender, e);
}
public virtual void POLine_UOM_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateQtyAvailable(sender, e);
}
private void UpdateQtyAvailable(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row == null) return;
    POLine row = (POLine)e.Row;

    foreach (INSiteStatus siteStatus in PXSelect<INSiteStatus,
        Where<INSiteStatus.inventoryID, Equal<Required<INSiteStatus.inventoryID>>,
          And<INSiteStatus.siteID, Equal<Required<INSiteStatus.siteID>>>>>.Select(sender.Graph, row.InventoryID, row.SiteID, row.UOM))
    {
        sender.SetValueExt<POLine_Extension.qtyOnHand>(row, siteStatus.QtyOnHand);
    }
}
```

[image]

When I add new one item and after select the UOM column in the PO detail Grid I want the Qty On Hand column's value divide by the value of the Conversion Factor (Qty On Hand/Conversion Factor ( Conversion Factor in Distribution => Stock Item => General Stetting => Unit of measure => Grid)

[image]

For example if the UOM value is CASE12(have the Conversion Factor = 12) mean my quality column's value have to divide by 12. Otherwise, the value don't change

Answer (score 1):

You can use `INUnitAttribute.ConvertFromBase` to convert the quantity value.

Here is a sample...

```
    public static bool TryConvertFromBaseQty<InventoryIDField>(PXCache sender, object row, string toUnit, Decimal convertingQty, out decimal? result) where InventoryIDField : IBqlField
    {
        result = null;

        try
        {
            result = INUnitAttribute.ConvertFromBase<InventoryIDField>(sender, row, toUnit, convertingQty, INPrecision.QUANTITY);

            return true;
        }
        catch (PXUnitConversionException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void UpdateQtyAvailable(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row == null) return;
        POLine row = (POLine)e.Row;

        foreach (INSiteStatus siteStatus in PXSelect<INSiteStatus,
            Where<INSiteStatus.inventoryID, Equal<Required<INSiteStatus.inventoryID>>,
                And<INSiteStatus.siteID, Equal<Required<INSiteStatus.siteID>>>>>.Select(sender.Graph, row.InventoryID, row.SiteID, row.UOM))
        {
            decimal? qtyOnHandInPoUom = 0m;
            if (TryConvertFromBaseQty<POLine.inventoryID>(sender, row, row.UOM,
                siteStatus.QtyOnHand.GetValueOrDefault(), out qtyOnHandInPoUom))
            {
                sender.SetValueExt<POLine_Extension.qtyOnHand>(row, qtyOnHandInPoUom);
                break;
            }

            sender.SetValueExt<POLine_Extension.qtyOnHand>(row, siteStatus.QtyOnHand);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's work but there is one problem. When the quality on hand of the item change in the database , I see in the old PO my customize quality on hand updated but it's not divided by the UOM column. For example in the pictuce PO 000008 after i change the UOM from bottle to case12, the On Hand column change from 85 to 85/12 but when I release the receipt the On hand value change from 85 to 90 i go back to this 000008 PO, the on hand column appear to be 90 and the UOM column is still CASE12. It's irrational, I want it to be 90/12. Please help me thank you !

Comment: you need to use field selecting for the unbound field. You cannot use updated events as the PO doesn't update on change of item qty on hand. Your unbound field would be set on page refresh in field selecting

Comment: Can you be specific for me please I am newbie. I need you to update your answer with all the code that I need to write with step by step (delete my old code is completely okay). I see this question is still related to the title "process Qty on hand base on UOM) so I think it is not good ideal to start a new question (And if I do it's gonna be to long and i don't know how to start). I need your help I'm stuck

Comment: Qty on hand shouldn't be saved to the DB. Use field selecting. This post is the same request but on opportunity. you can update for your page and display as a column in the grid rather than the grid footer.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45025533/how-to-display-product-availability-in-opportunity-products-grid-footer/45034612#45034612