# How do I add the Inventory Availability Status to Custom Grid like SO301000

Tags: acumatica

We are adding a custom screen that utilizes Site ID and Inventory ID in the row of the defined grid on the page.  We would like to add the Inventory Availability details as shown on SO301000 (Sales Order Entry graph).

A) How do I access the status area of the grid to place text.
B) Is there a standard method that I can access for the text used on SO301000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature is called `StatusField`.

You define the status field on the grid ASPX control:

```
<px:PXGrid ID="grid" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" StatusField="Availability">
```

It can be set with a FieldSelecting event:

```
public void SOLine_Availability_FieldSelecting(PXCache sender, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e)
```

Sales order screen lumps it with the allocation custom data view which makes it hard to re-use:

```
public LSSOLine lsselect;
```

In `LSSOLine` class you'll find the Availability_FieldSelecting method that computes the value:

```
public override void Availability_FieldSelecting(PXCache sender, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    var fetchMode = ((SOLine) e.Row)?.Completed == true
        ? AvailabilityFetchMode.None
        : AvailabilityFetchMode.ExcludeCurrent;
    IQtyAllocated availability = AvailabilityFetch(sender, (SOLine)e.Row, fetchMode | AvailabilityFetchMode.TryOptimize);

    if (availability != null)
    {
        PXResult<InventoryItem, INLotSerClass> item = ReadInventoryItem(sender, ((SOLine)e.Row).InventoryID);

        decimal unitRate = INUnitAttribute.ConvertFromBase<SOLine.inventoryID, SOLine.uOM>(sender, e.Row, 1m, INPrecision.NOROUND);
        availability.QtyOnHand = PXDBQuantityAttribute.Round((decimal)availability.QtyOnHand * unitRate);
        availability.QtyAvail = PXDBQuantityAttribute.Round((decimal)availability.QtyAvail * unitRate);
        availability.QtyNotAvail = PXDBQuantityAttribute.Round((decimal)availability.QtyNotAvail * unitRate);
        availability.QtyHardAvail = PXDBQuantityAttribute.Round((decimal)availability.QtyHardAvail * unitRate);

        if(IsAllocationEntryEnabled)
        {
            Decimal? allocated = PXDBQuantityAttribute.Round((decimal)(((SOLine)e.Row).LineQtyHardAvail ?? 0m) * unitRate); ;
            e.ReturnValue = PXMessages.LocalizeFormatNoPrefix(Messages.Availability_AllocatedInfo,
                    sender.GetValue<SOLine.uOM>(e.Row), FormatQty(availability.QtyOnHand), FormatQty(availability.QtyAvail), FormatQty(availability.QtyHardAvail), FormatQty(allocated));
        }
        else
            e.ReturnValue = PXMessages.LocalizeFormatNoPrefix(Messages.Availability_Info,
                    sender.GetValue<SOLine.uOM>(e.Row), FormatQty(availability.QtyOnHand), FormatQty(availability.QtyAvail), FormatQty(availability.QtyHardAvail));


        AvailabilityCheck(sender, (SOLine)e.Row, availability);
    }
    else
    {
        //handle missing UOM
        INUnitAttribute.ConvertFromBase<SOLine.inventoryID, SOLine.uOM>(sender, e.Row, 0m, INPrecision.QUANTITY);
        e.ReturnValue = string.Empty;
    }

    base.Availability_FieldSelecting(sender, e);
}
```

I would advise to skip using LSSOLine and just copy it's FieldSelecting method.

That approach is documented in more detail in this other answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45034612/7376238

Comment: Trying to reuse LSSOLine does appear to be pretty challenging in my use case.  Would be nice if availability could be modified in standard code to allow something like string availability = GetAvailability(int? inventoryID, int? subItemID, int? siteID, SOLine sOLine)l so that we can make a standard call and optionally pass the SOLine when it relates (null just gets current availability).  But for now I'll use the code sample you pointed me to that Brendan posted as a base and try to merge the data/formats as shown in your post for consistency.  Thanks again!