# Add text to the back of the grid, on the screen AP302000

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I would like to know if you can enter text in the back of the grid

[image: Here example]

Could you tell me if you can add a text, thanks to everyone?

Comment: Similar Q&A here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45025533/how-to-display-product-availability-in-opportunity-products-grid-footer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that. The feature is called `StatusField`.

To use it you need to define a DAC field of type `PXString` in the DAC bounded to the grid details. This field will hold the text value displayed in the grid footer and can change for each record that is selected in the grid.

In the ASPX page you need to set the `StatusField` property on the grid control to the name of the PXString DAC field you added (ex: Availability):

```
<px:PXGrid ID="grid" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" StatusField="Availability">
```

To populate the value of the DAC field you can use a `FieldSelecting` event:

```
public virtual void SOLine_Availability_FieldSelecting(PXCache sender, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    // Set text that appear in footer
    e.ReturnValue = "Text to be displayed in grid footer.";
}
```

**EDIT:**

To add a link control instead of a text block you need to use JavaScript. 
Note that those types of changes are likely not allowed by Acumatica ISV Certification program.

You can refer to this answer if you need to know how to add JavaScript to an Acumatica web page:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56008485/7376238

For your use case you need to identify the HTML ID of the grid footer. You can use the browser HTML inspect element feature for that:
[image]

I tested this JavaScript for creating the link control, you'll need to replace the 'ctl00_[...]' ID for the one of your target grid footer:

```
var gridFooter = document.getElementById("ctl00_phG_tab_t0_grid_ab").getElementsByTagName("nobr")[0];
var link = document.createElement('a');
var linkText = document.createTextNode("link description");
link.appendChild(linkText);
link.title = "link title";
link.href = "http://example.com";
gridFooter.parentNode.replaceChild(link, gridFooter);
```

This is the end result:
[image]

Comment: Hello friend, thanks for your answer, what I want to do is put a difficult word, which never changes, can you do that?

Comment: It is essentially the same, you can follow the example for that too. 
Would you like that I add more detailed steps?

Comment: If you please, do the example.

Comment: A question? You can put a hyperlink inside the bar.

Comment: Yes but it is a different approach for that (JavaScript) as I don't think LinkCommand property will work in the grid footer. I edited my question to show how to do that.

Comment: Excellent friend, he helped me a lot, thanks for your help.